# In yii i am trying to submit from using js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

I am trying to submit from using function but it show error

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

my form code

```
 <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'action'=>'/microsite/Photoupload?id='.$model->id,
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'id'=>'xxxx',
'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,

)); ?>

<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">    
    <?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('formname','photo');?>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($specialdeal,'photo'); ?>         
    <?php echo $form->fileField($specialdeal,'photo',array('class'=>'login_text','disabled'=>$disabled));?> <?php echo $form->error($specialdeal,'photo',array('class'=>'form_error')); ?>  
</div>

<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 datsun_photo">
    <?php echo CHtml::Button('Submit', array('name' => 'submit','onclick'=>'submitfunc("xxxx");')); ?>
```

my js code

```
function submitfunc(formid){
    var id = '#'+formid;
    $(id).submit();
}
```

I am using jquery v1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

**1st suggestion:** Close your form by `<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>`

**2nd suggestion:** Use yii `registerScript` something like below

```
<?php
     Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script_1', "
         function submitfunc(formid){
         $('#'+formid).submit();
     }",CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
?>
```

Comment: i am already close the from  <?php $this->endWidget(); ?> . Also i try to add 2nd suggestion but it also not work.:(